# How create UART Pass through in Microcontroller

Tags: embedded, microcontroller

I'm trying to create a UART Pass through for one of my project. But i could not figure out how i should tie the pins of microcontroller. I'm using embedded C & Keil for programming.

1. I'm using NXP p89lpc954 Microcontroller(8051 based) for this purpose.
2. My requirement is as shown below in the fig
   [image]
3. I'm controlling a sensor through UART port. Under normal operation microcontroller program communicates with the sensor using UART-1 Port. But when i connect the micrcontroller UART-0 port to host computer, i want the host computer to directly communicate with the sensor by creating a pass through between UART-0 & UART-1.

Could any one suggest any idea how we can achieve this.

Comment: There's a lot of talent on Stack Overflow, but I think you will get better answers elsewhere. You might try [Electrical Engineering Stack Exchange](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/), and come back to Stack Overflow when you have programming and development questions. I don't know enough about the topic, but it seems kind of broad, and it may not be answerable on a quorum like the Stack Exchange network.

Comment: @jww : ... except that this *is* as software problem that Vinod *thinks* is a hardware problem.

Comment: It isn't clear why the computer can't be connected directly to the sensor. You can use hardware to solve who speaks with it. Why does the data have to pass through the microcontroller?

Answer (score 4):

It is not normally possible to directly and transparently connect one UART to another.  You will have to provide appropriate software to transfer data from one UART to another.

If both UARTs run at the same baud rate this may be relatively simple - you can read the Rx register from one UART and write the value to the TX register of the other (and vice-versa for bi-directional comms).  If you implement this using UART interrupt handlers, it can be more-or less transparent to other code running on the MCU. For this to work without buffering, you have to be certain you can transfer the data from one UART to the other before a hardware overrun can occur - your hardware may or may not have a FIFO, so hardware buffering may be as little as the Rx register and the input shift register (two bytes). If there are other software operations occurring that may interfere with this operation, you may still need buffering.

If the baud-rates differ, you will need to provide buffering at least to the slower of the two ports, and you will not be able to stream data from the fast port to the slow one - there must be pauses in the data stream to prevent buffer exhaustion.

On some devices it may be possible to reduce the software overhead significantly by using DMA transfers (unlikely on your part I imagine).

However you do it you will still need software to enable and configure the UARTs - there is no hardware-only or simple "pin-pin" pass-through solution.

Comment: @dwelch : As the name implies, in *asynchronous* communications small clock mismatch is not in fact a problem.  The receiver synchronises on each start-bit, using it to determine the sample point for the following frame  (data bits, optional parity bit, stop-bit) so streaming is possible even with clock rates mismatched by as much as +/-5% for a 10 bit N,8,1 frame - the receiver simply runs at the *frame rate* of the transmitter,.  The two UARTs in question are in the *same* microcontroller and therefore (most likely) clock domain so potentially require no buffering for identical baud rate.

Comment: Actually, the fact that they have the same clock *does not* necessarily mean it will work without buffering.  If the sender is running a little faster, but still within range of reception, it can produce more characters per unit time than the MCU can resend at its idea of proper timing.  However, if the incoming pipe is kept full, even buffering won't fix the problem as the buffer would eventually overflow.  Of course most applications don't keep the pipe constantly full, but rather have bursts of data with gaps between.

Comment: @ChirsStratton :  I'll explain that again: The stop bit is time to resync the next frame it is essentially a forced gap.  The UART resyncs on the leading edge of the start bit, and sets the sample point to hit the nominal centre of each bit for the following frame. The UART sample clock runs faster than the bit rate, typically 5x in order to be within 10% of the bit centre, giving wide bit-rate mismatch tolerance.

Comment: You are still missing the issue.  The UART can receive fine - the problem is that means it can receive faster than it will transmit, so a situation can occur where the retransmission cannot keep up with the reception.

Comment: @ChrisStratton : Ah - yes, I concede that point.  No amount of buffering will resolve that problem if the data streams indefinitely.  It will extend the time a mismatched streaming burst can be sustained.  If the UARTs incorporate a FIFO that may be sufficient without software buffering depending on the nature of the data stream.  We do not know the nature of the sensor, but it would be unusual for a UART connected device to be use continuous streaming rather than periodic burst, but it is true that burst length and timing mismatch may need to be considered.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend looking to see if there is a UART pass through bit in a UART config register or a routing register. Other than that I would just use fly wires from the PC UART to the Sensor UART.